# Interesting use of the C# yield keyword in Nerd Dinner tutorial

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield

Working through a tutorial (Professional ASP.NET MVC - Nerd Dinner), I came across this snippet of code:

```
public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations() {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Title required", "Title");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Description required","Description");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostedBy))
        yield return new RuleViolation("HostedBy required", "HostedBy");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Address required", "Address");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Country required", "Country");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactPhone))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# required", "ContactPhone");
    if (!PhoneValidator.IsValidNumber(ContactPhone, Country))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# does not match country", "ContactPhone");
    yield break;
}
```

I've read up on `yield`, but I guess my understanding is still a little bit hazy. What it seems to do is create an object that *allows* cycling through the items in a collection without actually *doing* the cycling unless and until it's absolutely necessary.

This example is a little strange to me, though. What I think it's doing is delaying the creation of any `RuleViolation` instances until the programmer actually requests a specific item in the collection using either `for each` or a LINQ extension method like `.ElementAt(2)`.

Beyond this, though, I have some questions:

1. When do the conditional parts of the `if` statements get evaluated? When `GetRuleViolations()` is called or when the enumerable is actually iterated? In other words, if the value of `Title` changes from `null` to `Really Geeky Dinner` between the time that I call `GetRuleViolations()` and the time I attempt to actually iterate over it, will `RuleViolation("Title required", "Title")` be created or not?
2. Why is `yield break;` necessary? What is it really doing here?
3. Let's say `Title` is null or empty. If I call `GetRuleViolations()` then iterate over the resulting enumerable two times in a row, how many times will `new RuleViolation("Title required", "Title")` be called?

Comment: The .Net compiler turns this syntactic sugar into a more bastardized form. Compile the sample and then load IL in the reflector. You should be abe to understand exactly what is going on there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A function that contains `yield` commands is treated differently than a normal function. What is happening behind the scenes when that function is called, is that an anonymous type is constructed of the specific `IEnumerable` type of the function, the function creates an object of that type and returns it. The anonymous class contains logic that executes the body of the function up until the next `yield` command for every time the `IEnumerable.MoveNext` is called. It is a bit misleading, the body of the function is not executed in one batch like a normal function, but rather in pieces, each piece executes when the enumerator moves one step forward.

With regards to your questions:

1. As I said, each `if` gets executed when you iterate to the next element.
2. `yield break` is indeed not necessary in the example above. What it does is it terminates the enumeration.
3. Each time you iterate over the enumerable, you force the execution of the code again. Put a breakpoint on the relevant line and test for yourself.

Comment: +1 really clear and helpful answer, thanks. Just one minor followup question if you don't mind: Can you think of an example where `yield break` *is* necessary?

Comment: Minor clarification - you mean `IEnumerator[<T>]` in a few places where you say `IEnumerable[<T>]`.

Comment: So in the example the `yield break` is necessary, because if no `RuleViolation` is created, it would throw an exception, right?

Comment: By "empty set" do you mean none of the `if` statements evaluate to true, or do you mean `yield break` is needed as a placeholder if I haven't yet added any `if` statements to my method? (Or both?)

Comment: `yield break` is not necessary here. It is only necessary in case you need to stop the enumeration somewhere inside the function body, before the execution reaches its natural end.

Comment: @Aviad, this is true even if there are no if statements in the body of the method?

Comment: Okay, but clearly, `private IEnumerable<string> Enumerate() { }` will get you a "not all code paths return a value error". So, I think this allows me to conclude the following: you need `yield break` either (1) as a placeholder if you have no other return statements (yield or otherwise) in your method or (2) "in case you need to stop the enumeration somewhere inside the function body, before the execution reaches its natural end."

Comment: Yes, the function body must contain the keyword `yield` for this to work. Otherwise the compiler would treat it as a normal function (read the first sentence in my answer again :-) )

Answer (score 6):

1) Take this simpler example:

```
public void Enumerate()
{
    foreach (var item in EnumerateItems())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateItems()
{
    yield return "item1";
    yield return "item2";
    yield break;
}
```

Each time you call `MoveNext()` from the `IEnumerator` the code returns from the `yield` point and moves to the next executable line of code.

2) `yield break;` will tell the `IEnumerator` that there is nothing more to enumerate.

3) once per enumeration.

Using `yield break;`

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateUntilEmpty()
{
    foreach (var name in nameList)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) yield break;
        yield return name;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Sure about the "3) once"? As far as I understand this is reevaluated every time (see the other two answers here).

Comment: If you make a list, why not iterate over it anyway? The `yield` way enables you not to explicitly construct a list. In your case for example:
    public IEnumerable<string> Enumerate()
    {
        yield return "item1";
        yield return "item2";
    }

Comment: Thanks, that accomplishes what I originally wanted to show, a simple version of his example.

Comment: `yield break` is not necessary in your first example either. In your second example it is of course.

Answer (score 2):

Short version:

1: The yield is the magic "Stop and come back later" keyword, so the if statements in front of the "active" one have been evaluated.

2: yield break explicitly ends the enumeration (think "break" in a switch case)

3: Every time. You can cache the result, of course, by turning it into a List for example and iterating over that afterwards.